# Spring Cloud Feign Client @RequestParam with List parameter can not join with custom delimiter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, openfeign

```java
@CollectionFormat(feign.CollectionFormat.CSV)
[...]
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/search/findByIdIn")
Resources<MyClass> get(@RequestParam("ids") List<Long> ids);
```

creates a request like: `/search/findByIdIn?ids=1,2,3` ... however, `feign.CollectionFormat` does not support custom separation characters, I want to perform a request with values separated by `;`, like `/search/findByIdIn?ids=1;2;3`.

How can I achieve this?